# MySQL: Complex queries or tracking/counter fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, data-modeling

I'm just thinking about MySQL database design and there are often situations where

- A particular action is or is not carried out and consequently data is or is not stored in the database
- Whether or not a user undertook a particular action is displayed statistically

An example of this would be:

> A user does or does not fill out a survey. If they do fill out a survey, the data they provide is stored in the database. The total number of users who filled out the survey is displayed.

Now, in order to get the number of users who filled out the survey, we could either

- create a field of type `BOOL` which is set to `TRUE` on suvey completion; we then calculate the number of users who completed the survey using a simple `COUNT(*) WHERE field=TRUE`
- calculate the number of users who filled out the survey using the data they provided by joining the users and survey results tables and grouping on the user

This isn't a particularly complex example, but there are cases where without the `BOOL` flag, queries can be become very **complex and expensive**. But the flag is an almost unnecessary addition to the database tables - we use it only for convenience. Also it means we have to ensure that we `UPDATE` all user flags at the relevant time, as well as storing user data.

**What would be your approach to this kind of problem?** For smaller applications, i'll usually just write complex queries and cache their results (occasionally using *views* to make things more manageable). But in larger applications, with potentially many joins, I might be tempted to flag the users with an action field so that reads are simpler and cheaper.

Comment: People may scoff at the data-integrity, but indeed, on bigger projects where the database can clearly become the bottleneck I do use 'cache' values sometimes. More long-lived then query cache, easier to control/update then simple key/value caches. MOstly they live in the database, but depending on the data & the percentage of requests needed, they may still be generated the 'long way around', but cached elsewhere (like a store like Memcache et al.). Overall, I've come to about the same conclusion as you have, but of course it varies from project to project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is called a "denormalized view", i.e. a table that contains results which can be computed from other data already in the database. The reason to do this is indeed performance, whether to do this or not depends on the cost of (re-)generating the data, the effort in your code required to keep it coherent, and the extra amount of database space to store the computed values.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is an indexed view (SQL Server terminology) or a materialized view (Oracle terminology) or a materialized query table (DB2 terminology). All those solutions keep the data up to date in real time. No maintenance.

When your platform doesn't support those kinds of database objects, you have to resort to using a table, along with all the other things necessary to keep the data right. You can keep the data right with

- triggers
- cron jobs

If you use triggers, you should probably also run a periodic cron job to make sure the data stored matches the data calculated.

It helps that, in the real world, most of these kinds of requirements really *don't* have to be up to date in real time. These kinds of numbers usually support management decisions; a lag of even a day is often acceptable. (In other words, it sometimes helps to think of it as a data warehouse problem or as a report rather than as an OLTP problem.)  I've had to negotiate these kinds of requirements many times. I've never had anyone refuse to accept a two-hour update cycle. (But that's certainly application-dependent.)

Comment: Interesting. MySQL supports *views* of a sort, which in my applications can be useful. The idea of the problem as a data warehousing one is a very useful way of thinking about it.

Comment: Actually, I usually find it *most* helpful to think of a data warehouse as a materialized report.

Comment: MySQL supports SQL views, but that doesn't buy you much in terms of performance. That kind of view repeats its calculations and such every time you run it. A materialized view behaves like a base table; the data is *in* the view, rather than being looked up by the view. And the dbms takes the responsibility of keeping it up to date, instead of you having to do that with triggers or cron jobs.

Answer (score 1):

> calculate the number of users . . . by joining the users and
>   survey results tables and grouping on
>   the user

If you can join the users and the survey results tables, then the survey results table must have a user identifier, right?  If that's right, you don't need to join those two tables to determine the number of users who completed a survey.

Comment: Yes, erm, well pointed out, but you misunderstand the motives of the exmaple. What about if we needed to count the number of times users from a particular department filed out a survey? Granted this is only one additional join, but it can really grow in complexity. See @Wim answer below.

Comment: No, I got the motives. I just didn't assume that, having overlooked one or two simple issues, you didn't also overlook a bunch more. That's an observation, not a criticism. And it's not one *additional* join, it's usually *just one join* for any other table that contains a user identifier.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't think I gave enough time to the example.

Comment: @ddawber: That's always the risk in simplifying. A lot of times, simplified questions "optimize away" the most relevant answers of the most experienced people.